# Dataframe value matching in Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, lookup

I have a problem I am working on for days. I have 2 data-frames as below. Index by definition means a set of TEST, NAME and SEQUENCE triple which is unique. Goal is to get the 'index' value from the index file which matches:

one of the sequence values such as for [111,222,333] in config ( for example can be 111 **or** 222 **or** 333) **and** the TEST **and** the NAME.

Config file is what matters, and aim is to find the index values corresponding to that. Nothing that do not exist in config should show up in the output file. I want to have a final output which includes: INDEX, TEST, NAME and SEQUENCE. So the final output will be a subset of the config file but it will only include one SEQUENCE (instead of 3) and corresponding TEST and NAME and INDEX. such as :

**Example output file:**

```
index   TEST    NAME    SEQUENCE
901922  A       john       111
238394  C       ashley     555
930293  B       sam        444
```

I have tried to write a for loop but was not successful with the indexing as below:

```
for x in range(0, config.shape[0]):
    find1=eval(config.SEQUENCE[x])
    find1='|'.join(str(i) for i in find1)  
    find1 = '(' + find1 + ')'
```

First dataframe : **config**

```
SEQUENCE    TEST    NAME
[111,222,333]   A   john
[222,444,888]   B   sam
[111,222,333]   A   ashley
[999,777,555]   C   ashley
[111,222,333]   D   john
[111,222,333]   A   john
                G   kelly
```

Second dataframe: **index**

```
index   TEST    NAME    SEQUENCE
901922  A       john       111
930293  B       sam        444
238203  A       ashley     888
238394  C       ashley     555
483472  D       john       777
901922  A       john       111
264225  F       greg       111
465126  A       mary       555
554216  B       peter      333
```

Comment: this is not related to sql, so I removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to first left join the two table on `test` and `name`, and then drop rows where the `sequence` in `index` is not found in `config`:

```
ind2 = index.set_index(['test', 'name'])
out = config.join(ind2, ['test', 'name'], 'left', lsuffix='_config', rsuffix='_index')
out['sequence_config'] = out.apply(lambda x: x['sequence_index'] in x['sequence_config'] if x['sequence_config'] is not None else False, axis=1)

out = out[out['sequence_config']].set_index('index').drop_duplicates().drop(
    'sequence_config', axis=1).rename(columns={'sequence_index': 'sequence'})
```

This gives:

```
            name test  sequence
index                          
901922.0    john    A     111.0
930293.0     sam    B     444.0
238394.0  ashley    C     555.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Your DataFrame contains a column of strings that look like lists,
# but we want to work with a column of actual Python lists.
# Convert strings to lists with this:
from ast import literal_eval
config['SEQUENCE'] = config['SEQUENCE'].apply(literal_eval)

# Split these newly formed lists into separate columns
split = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(config.SEQUENCE.values.tolist()), 
                   config[['TEST', 'NAME']]], axis=1)
split
     0    1    2 TEST    NAME
0  111  222  333    A    john
1  222  444  888    B     sam
2  111  222  333    A  ashley
3  999  777  666    C  ashley
4  111  222  333    D    john
5  111  222  333    A   john


# Melt or "unpivot" the DF so that each row holds only one sequence
melted = split.melt(id_vars=['TEST', 'NAME'], 
                    value_name='SEQUENCE').drop('variable', axis=1)
melted
   TEST    NAME  SEQUENCE
0     A    john       111
1     B     sam       222
2     A  ashley       111
3     C  ashley       999
4     D    john       111
5     A   john       111
6     A    john       222
7     B     sam       444
8     A  ashley       222
9     C  ashley       777
10    D    john       222
11    A   john       222
12    A    john       333
13    B     sam       888
14    A  ashley       333
15    C  ashley       666
16    D    john       333
17    A   john       333


# Default behaviour of pd.merge gives us what we want!
# Note that the duplicate row arises from the duplicate in the DF named index.
pd.merge(melted, index)
  TEST  NAME  SEQUENCE   index
0    A  john       111  901922
1    A  john       111  901922
2    B   sam       444  930293


pd.merge(melted, index)['index'].unique()
array([901922, 930293])
```

Comment: I applied the code above -- my split still has the sequence triple together for some reason, what am I missing? For example it remains like  [111,222,333]

Comment: Weird... What is the exact output of `config['SEQUENCE'][0]`, including quotation marks? Maybe your `SEQUENCE` column contains strings that look like Python lists...?

Comment: The answer to your question is : [111,222,333]. Do you keep the square brackets of SEQUENCE in your code? they need to be there. That may be why ?

Comment: It may be that your DataFrame actually holds a column of *strings* that look like lists, whereas I assumed your column held Python lists. See my edited answer: I added two lines at the beginning to convert the strings in `config['SEQUENCE']` to Python lists. The rest of the code should work after that.

Comment: Sorry but -- when I run the first two lines: unexpected EOF while parsing error occurs.. Is it cos this is Python 2.7?

Comment: Should still work in 2.7. What is `type(config['SEQUENCE'][0])`?

Comment: type(config['SEQUENCE'][0]) = str

Comment: OK, that confirms that the `SEQUENCE` column of `config` contains strings that need to be evaluated into lists using `literal_eval`. The `unexpected EOF` error suggests there may be one or more empty strings in `config['SEQUENCE']`. Try `config2 = config.replace('', pd.np.nan).dropna()` and then `config2['SEQUENCE'] = config2['SEQUENCE'].apply(literal_eval)`

Comment: Thanks for your continuous effort. config2 returns empty.

Comment: That's weird... If `config` really holds what you've provided in your question, then it shouldn't end up empty. I'm all out of ideas, except to inspect your data import steps, and somehow get `config['SEQUENCE']` to be a column of lists, rather than strings that look like lists.

Comment: Unfortunately, merge not working - returns an empty list

Comment: The problem is that your `config` DataFrame does not hold actual Python lists, but rather *strings* that hold the characters that define Python lists. (`literal_eval()` needs to be applied to each string, after dropping empty strings.) Until you solve that problem, my code will unfortunately not work.